# How to set dart & flutter to default when I'm buliding flutter projects

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code to create and build a flutter project.

But every time I press F5 to build, vs code always asks me to select the environment. It's very annoying.

How to set dart & flutter to default when I'm buliding flutter projects.

[image]

Comment: After I build 100? times or more, I don't remember. Vs code stopped ask me this question. Maybe he is tired???j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VSCode you need a launch configuration

If you don't have the following file, create one:

```
.vscode/launch.json
```

With contents of:

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flutter",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.dart"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just make sure the program is pointing to your main dart file that has `runApp` in it

Comment: debug - open config, I found it.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    }
    ]
}
```